# Fixed point of a generating function

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions

> For $p \in (0,1)$ and $b \in [0,p]$, define a probability measure by
>   $$P(Z = k) = b(1-p)^{k-1}$$
>   if $k \ge 1$, 
>   $$P(Z=k) = 1 - b/p$$
>   if $k = 0$. Show that $s = \frac{1- b/p}{1-p}$ is a fixed point of the probability generating function of $Z$.

I simply don't understand why it doesn't work out the way I did it. By definiton:

$$g_Z(s) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty P(Z = k)s^k = (1-b/p)\sum_{k = 1}^\infty b(1-p)^{k-1}s^k.$$
Multplying both sides by $(1-p)$ yields
$$g_Z(s)(1-p) = b(1-b/p) \sum_{k=1}^\infty ((1-p)s)^k = b(1-b/p) \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1 - b/p)^k.$$
Starting with $k = 0$, this becomes the geometric series, so we shift the index and receive
$$b(1-b/p)(1-b/p)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-b/p)^k = b(1-b/p)^2 \frac{1}{b/p} = (1- b/p)^2 p.$$

But
$$(1- b/p)^2 p \neq 1 - b/p,$$
so even after dividing by $(1-p)$, this doesn't become by desired fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

Your probability generating function is incorrect. It should be 
$$
g_{Z}(s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(Z=k)s^k=1-b/p+\sum_{k=1}^\infty b(1-p)^{k-1}s^k=1-b/p+\frac{bs}{1-(1-p)s}
$$
and solve for  $g_{Z}(s)=s$.

Comment: Ah, damn, my mystake was that I multiplied the series with $(1-b/p)$, but I should've added it up obviously. I don't quite understand your approach though. Why don't you simplify first before calculating the series?